# how to use gif images in UIImageView iOS

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview, show

i have one gif image file having 4 images , i like to display these  images  in UIImage view one by one line image.animation . please guide is it possible to display or shoul i use alternat tell me .

thank you .

Comment: Welcome ...Please do search before posting a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744682/display-animated-gif-in-ios

Comment: thank you Lithu very much you got my point of problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will help you , for gif link..https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif more help please feel free to ask

Answer (score 3):

[FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) is a performant open source animated GIF engine for iOS:

- Plays multiple GIFs simultaneously with a playback speed comparable
  to desktop browsers
- Honors variable frame delays
- Behaves gracefully under memory pressure
- Eliminates delays or blocking during the first playback loop
- Interprets the frame delays of fast GIFs the same way modern browsers do

It's a well-tested component that I wrote to [power all GIFs in Flipboard](http://engineering.flipboard.com/2014/05/animated-gif/).

Comment: Sadly, this pod has been unmaintained for 9 months now.

Answer (score 0):

yes it possible in iOS,here i enclosed one URL below.please refer this for your concept,even i did it with help of this link.

https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif

hope i held you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"loading" withExtension:@"gif"];
        UIImage *loadingImage = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
        self.dataImageView.animationImages = loadingImage.images;
        self.dataImageView.animationDuration = loadingImage.duration;
        self.dataImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
        self.dataImageView.image = loadingImage.images.lastObject;
        [self.dataImageView startAnimating];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can add those 4 images in one Plist and do the following code. I hope it will work

```
    NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PhotesArray" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSArray *imageNames = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"Photos"];
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[imageNames count]; i++) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
//Normal animation
self.dataImageView.animationImages = images;
self.dataImageView.animationDuration = 3.0;
[self.dataImageView startAnimating];
```