# Add an image to my button in ios is blue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uibutton

I have a gif in my button, but it displays as just blue box.

```
 (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
    {
    //[self setTitle:@"Register" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Person.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//setting image on button.
}
return self;
```

}

The image was added correctly to xcode.  What gives?

Comment: Try to use `UIImageView` to display gif.

Comment: iOS doesn't support GIF images

Comment: @chris you have to give your response about your question's answer's this is not a way to getting Help. atlist you give reply that user who give you answer about your issue. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS GIF image not supported so if you wish to do set Image With Animation do like bellow code:-

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"], nil];
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
[yourButton addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

For more Check this Bellow link about iOS suported GIF:-

[Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3910635?start=0&tstart=0)

[Display animated GIF in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744682/display-animated-gif-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set [button backgroundimage] and it will set any format of image to you

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage claims to have Animated gif support!

Check it out:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage