# Display gif image without using UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gif

into my app I need to display gif image on my view, but don't use the UIWebview to display it. So have any way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look this :-https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Animated-GIF-iPhone

Comment: Same Question here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744682/display-animated-gif-in-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this

https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif

It provides the following category:

```
+[UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:(NSURL *)url]
```

allowing you to simply:

```
#import "UIImage+animatedGIF.h"
UIImage* mygif = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rotating_earth_(large).gif"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use this project from gothub
https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif

Example

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"gif"];
self.dataImageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
self.urlImageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:url];

url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"variableDuration" withExtension:@"gif"];
self.variableDurationImageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:url];
```

Comment: up vote for good link, So just have only answer is accept so this is must the earlier answer.Thanks for your help.