# gif files from php to iphone

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, iphone

How to show gif files got from php using json web services in iphone? We need to get gif files in json web services and show in image view, but we show gif in image view then it does not show required animation. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display animated GIF in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744682/display-animated-gif-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, project from git it may help you.

https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/

or for more information find the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744682/display-animated-gif-in-ios) previously asked on stack overflow.