# IOS Support to display GIF animated image?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview, ios8

I want to display video background in my app. Finally  I got the below example to view video backgorund using gif image.

Some people said Apples don't allow animated gif image in iOS and one stack over flow ticket apple now allowing gif image.

So please conform me apple now allow the animated gif image to diaplay or advice me how to created video back ground for my app ?

[Example Link](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2)

[Stack-overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744682/display-animated-gif-in-ios)

Answer (score -1):

Chq out this Link FOr Official Apple Refrence UI Image Doc.. Thats Simply Say that the gif image will supported in this apple uiimage...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/

[image]

Comment: Can you please tel me how to animate gif image in uimage?

Comment: This says that you can put a gif image into a UIImageView. But the OP specifically asks about animated gifs. This mentions nothing about animated gifs and IIRC UIImageView will not animate them natively.

Comment: When I use `imageview.image = [uiimage imagenamed:"myGifImage"];` it gives me blank..

Comment: Than U Must be Use the Thired Party Api .. Like SdWebImage
From Here : https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

And Chnge Image From 
this methods.. :   
 [imgVw setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLstr] usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];