# Loop through array contents' names

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, loops, uiimage

I want to display a .gif (so like automatically playing video), therefore I found out I need to use an array of `UIImages`. Now, I have a video containing 96 images, so I would like to use a loop for naming them. Is that possible?

I tried the following, which does unfortunatly not work:

```
for (int i = 0; i<97; i++) {
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"%d", i];
}
```

So what I want to do with the loop is something like this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    for (int i = 0; i<97; i++) {
                        [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
                    }
                    , nil];
```

So is there a way using for-loops in an array?
Some ideas?

Comment: It looks like you wanted `[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];` but I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve as you don't do anything with the images

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks! I want to use them in an array

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744682/display-animated-gif-in-ios

Comment: @Paulw11 see my edit for what I want to do exactly

Comment: Just give some prefix to your image names and then you can use code in above link

Comment: You could use the `UIImageView animatedImagesWithImages: duration:` method to animate your array of images. But with 96 images it may use a lot of memory, depending on the size of the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property like this in your .h file :

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *images;
```

initialise it in viewDidLoad method like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

You need to do following :

```
for (int i = 0; i<97; i++) 
{
    UIImage *currentImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    [self.images addObject:currentImage];// images is a NSMutableArray
}
```

If you want to animate those images, you can do following (Assuming you have a UIImageView object with name imageView) :

```
imageView.animationImages = self.images;
[imageView startAnimating];
```

Go through UIImageView class documentation for more options.

Comment: So, you said `images` is an Array, don't I have to declare it like `NSMutableArray *images;`? It then throws an error

Comment: Yes, you have to declare and initialise it.I assumed that you know how to do it. Declare it as a property and initialise it in the "viewDidLoad" method.

Comment: Ok, I declared it, but how do I initialize it? (Sorry but I am still beginner :/ )

Comment: Have you tried running your code? Because for me it says `No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'addImage:'`. I did everything as you said. Oh and it wanted me to use `_images` instead of `images`...

Comment: Sorry, its a typo. Please change addImage: to addObject:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65744/discussion-between-naga-mallesh-maddali-and-lige).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but if you want to show animation using a batch of images you could use following approach.

```
// 1. Create an array of images names. If you have images named 0.png, 1.png, ... 95.png:
NSMutableArray *imageNames = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < 96; i++)
{
    [imageNames addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
}

// 2. Create an array of images from array of names:

     NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [imageNames enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:obj]];
    }];

// 3. Assign it to UIImageView:

    self.imageView = [UIImageView new];
    [self.view addSubview: self.imageView];
    self.imageView.animationImages = images;
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 0.5;
    [self.imageView startAnimating];
```

You can find more at this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/)

Comment: sorry saw your answer too late, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

imagview have an  property ,that is animationImages.   you can add  your arrayNames to this property.then  it works

Comment: oh sorry  my  words simple， but it  is about  your question  ...my solution is same to sofa

Comment: well I knew how to do the .gif animation, I just wanted to shorten my code