# Animated image from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to load a value from my plist which is the base name of the animated image I want to create. Essentially, I want my plist to contain the name `image-.jpg`, and use the code to do the rest.

I've gotten the idea from here [Display animated GIF in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744682/display-animated-gif-in-ios)

and now I'm just trying to mix a plist into play. So far I've gotten this:

```
imageName.image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] valueForKey:@"imageName" duration:1.0f]];
```

The `valueForKey` is `image-.jpg`, so when iOS runs `animatedImageNamed` it would be `image-1.jpg`, `image-2.jpg`, etc.

My issue is that Xcode displays an error at `animatedImageNamed`, saying there's no known method for selector.

How can I fix this?

Comment: BTW - change `valueForKey:` to `objectForKey:` assuming you have an array of dictionary in your plist file. Better yet, use modern syntax: `myArray[indexValue][@"imageName"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the placement of ']' :) May be the statement should look like

```
imageName.image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] valueForKey:@"imageName"] duration:1.0f]
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. Dang. And for anyone that may be looking: using this method means your image extension doesn't matter (and you actually can't add the .jpg, .png, etc.) on your plist or image files.