# Load Animated gif in UIImageView IOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, gif, animated

I have this gif into my assets file [image: Gif]

The name of the assets is loading_apple but when I add the following code I get a nullpointer exception error:

```
let img = UIImage (named: "loading_apple")
```

So how can I show this gif ? :(

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Are you sure it's not "loading_apple.gif"?

Comment: yes, I have tried also with loading_apple.gif, other formats works perfectly

Comment: Try using an image literal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend breaking out the frames of that gif and use `animatedImageNamed:duration:` - you can name them all the similar name with a number change at the end. For instance:

`loading-1.png`
`loading-2.png`
`loading-3.png` etc.

Xcode will recognize you want multiple images and will play those through in order.

Look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744682/display-animated-gif-in-ios)

Comment: I have try this way:  let img = UIImage.animatedImageNamed("tmp",duration: 1.0)!, but I got the same error message: "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: You got it! Glad to help out

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using FLAnimatedImage https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Answer (score 0):

instead of storing the gif file, why don't u make use of `CAReplicatorLayer` refer this [link](http://www.ios-animations-by-emails.com/posts/2015-march) and this [link in objective c](http://ronnqvi.st/custom-activity-indicators-using-a-replicator-layer/), i took same code in second like and with some modification,

```
func spinTheCustomSpinner() -> Void {
    let aBar:CALayer = CALayer.init()
    aBar.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 25);
    aBar.cornerRadius = 4; //(8/2)
    aBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    aBar.position = CGPointMake(150.0, 150.0 + 35)

    let replicatorLayer:CAReplicatorLayer = CAReplicatorLayer.init()
    replicatorLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0,300,300)
    replicatorLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    replicatorLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    replicatorLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view!.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view!.bounds))
    let angle:CGFloat = CGFloat (2.0 * M_PI) / 12.0
    let transform:CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1.0)
    replicatorLayer.instanceCount = 12
    replicatorLayer.instanceTransform = transform
    replicatorLayer .addSublayer(aBar)
    self.view!.layer .addSublayer(replicatorLayer)

    aBar.opacity = 0.0
    let animationFade:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    animationFade.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
    animationFade.toValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
    animationFade.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animationFade.repeatCount = HUGE
    animationFade.duration = 1.0

    let aBarAnimationDuration:Double = 1.0/12.0
    replicatorLayer.instanceDelay = aBarAnimationDuration
    aBar .addAnimation(animationFade, forKey: "fadeAnimation")

}
```

if u use above with a view, show this view while loading and hide after loading, this is really cool and handy and there is no headache of storing the gif file and using a image view to load.

and by changing the properties of `aBar` layer u get different effects.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific gif you may want to use [`UIActivityIndicatorView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview) and make it animating with `startAnimating()`